# SoundPool in fragment not playing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, soundpool

I am trying to play a sound clip from a fragment, but the sound is not playing. I am not getting any errors in console and no crashing, just no sound is played. yes, my volume is up and nothing is muted. All relevant code is below

```
        int soundId;
        int currentSound;
        SoundPool sp;

        boolean pressed;
        boolean loaded;

        sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        currentSound = R.raw.whatarethose;
        sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int i, int i1) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(loaded) {
                    soundId = sp.load(getActivity(), currentSound, 1);

                    sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you mean in the emulator? Can you try it on a real device? I've had problems with the emulator not playing sound lately as well, but app worked fine on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the sound in the button click. try to load the sound after yu set the OnCompleteListener, before the click.

```
    int soundId;
    int currentSound;
    SoundPool sp;

    boolean pressed;
    boolean loaded;

    sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
    currentSound = R.raw.whatarethose;
    sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int i, int i1) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
    soundId = sp.load(getActivity(), currentSound, 1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(loaded) {
                sp.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        }
    });
```